# Solution for $f'' = \lambda f - g$ in $C_0(\Bbb{R})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

I don't find a suitable solution for the equation $f'' = \lambda f - g$, where $g\in C_0(\Bbb{R}) := \{f\in C(\Bbb{R}) \ | \ \lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = 0\}$ and $\lambda >0$. I search for $f\in C_0(\Bbb{R})\cap C^2(\Bbb{R}) $. With Picard-Lindelöf I know that there is a solution in $C^2(\Bbb{R})$, but unless I have another argument or a formula for the solution I can't determine that the solution is also in $C_0(\Bbb{R})$.

A formula or helpful references would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The solution need _not_ be in $C_0$.

Comment: Why? Because in fact this is a part of an exercise that I expect to be well posed. I just need any solution with this property for some arbitrary $\lambda$.

Comment: Suppose to simplify things that $\lambda =0$. Then the equation is $f''=g$, which you solve by integrating $g$ twice. That gives you a solution that's simply not in $C_c$. No point to asking how to prove something false.

Comment: But here is $\lambda > 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $u>0$ such that $u^2=\lambda$. You can solve your differenrial equation with the method of variation of constants. You solve the system $C_1^{\prime}\exp(ux)+C_2^{\prime}\exp(-ux)=0$ and $C_1^{\prime}u\exp(ux)-uC_2^{\prime}\exp(-ux)=-g$ , you get that the general solution $C_1(x)\exp(ux)+C_2(x)\exp(-ux)$ of your equation is :
$$h(x)=-\frac{1}{2u}\exp(ux)\int_0^xg(t)\exp(-ut)dt+\frac{1}{2u}\exp(-ux)\int_0^x g(t)\exp(ut)dt+a\exp(ux)+b\exp(-ux)$$ where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants.

Now you want to find $a,b$ such that $h$ is in $C_0$. If you write the first part of $h$ as $\frac{\exp(ux)}{2u}(2ua-\int_0^xg(t)\exp(-ut)dt)$, then letting $x\to +\infty$ show that we must have $2ua=\int_0^{+\infty}g(t)\exp(-ut)dt$, (a convergent integral) ( the second part goes to $0$, use that for $x$ large $|g(x)|$ is small). Do the same with the second part and $x\to -\infty$. This lead to
$$h(x)=\frac{\exp(ux)}{2u}\int_x^{+\infty}g(t)\exp(-ut)dt+\frac{\exp(-ux)}{2u}\int_{-\infty}^{x}g(t)\exp(ut)dt$$